# Prevent dev dependencies in Yarn 3 cache folder with PNP

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2

I am utilizing Yarn 3 with the Plug'n'Play (PNP) feature for zero-installation of the dependencies in my development environment, which works well. However, when I run a production build, the `.yarn/cache` folder also includes dev-dependencies, resulting in an increase in the overall size of the Docker image. Is there a way to only include the necessary dependencies in the `.yarn/cache` folder for the production build?